# how to add background image in nautilus 3.4.2

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04** and i want to know how to add image to **nautilus background**. I know there is a way to change it by editing the **nautilus.css** file but is there any graphical way to do it. Another thing i noticed that many themes dont have the **nautilus.css** file. If there is no graphical way then please tell me how can i change the background for all themes. Nautilus version is 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set custom background images in Nautilus any more, without doing it via the theme.

Comment: what about those themes that dont have the css file ?

Comment: Then they aren't setting a background image for Nautilus. There is no way to set a global image that doesn't change when you change themes for this.